# How to limit textField Max value in HH:MM:SS Formatter?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have 1 `UITexTField` and i allow used to enter numbers only in this "mm:ss" formate and for that i have used [StringFormatter](https://github.com/orucanil/StringFormatter)

Here is my code which works fine for above format.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField.accessibilityHint == ExerciseParam.kTime {
        let lastText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
        textField.text = lastText.format("nn:nn:nn", oldString: textField.text!)

        if lastText == "nn:nn:nn" {
            return false
        }
        else {

        }
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Want i want to do**

I want something like this. User can only enter max **60** in **hh:mm:ss**

**Valid Input ==> ** **60:56:55**

**InValid Input ==> ** **66:56:80**

If i enter invalid input in textfield then it automatically becomes 60:56:80 or it will automatically increase **MM** or **HH** value like **60:57:20**

How can i do this. please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To limit the keyboard type, you could set textfield keyboardType to numberPad only

```
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Here is an example solution, if you want to support "**HH**" in 24-hour clock, need to add more implementation.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let lastText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as String
    let formattedStr = lastText.format("nn:nn:nn", oldString: textField.text!)
    var rtn = formattedStr
    if formattedStr.count == 8 {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(\d{2})"#, options: [.caseInsensitive]) else {
            return false
        }
        let matches = regex.matches(in: formattedStr, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedStr.count))
        var inc = false // do increment
        var ary: [String] = []
        for match in matches.reversed() {
            let str = String(formattedStr[Range(match.range, in: formattedStr)!])
            var num: Int = Int(str)!
            if inc {
                num += 1
            }
            inc = num > 60
            let aStr = inc ? String(format: "%02d", num - 60) : String(format: "%02d", num)
            ary.append(aStr)
        }
        print("ary: \(String(describing: ary))")
        rtn = ary.reversed().joined(separator: ":")
    }
    textField.text = rtn
    return rtn == "nn:nn:nn"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try and let you know.